# Run script just when div with #id is loaded in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, document-ready

How can i run js-script just when `div` with `#id` is loaded in DOM ?

For what this is for me? Because i run js-script before `document.ready()` for `div` with `#id`, and i am not sure if this `div` with `#id` already exist.

ADDITIONAL

problem : when i put script in `document.ready()`, it is visible what willbe if i don't add this script for some seconds, but then - all is allright. So i write script outside of `document.ready()` and this helps. But i'm not sure that this will work every time.

Comment: What element is `#id`? Why can't you run your script within `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: That's what document.ready() is made for, actually.

Comment: put script tag containing logic just after the DIV #id tag or better, post more of your relevant code and what you expect so maybe someone could understand it

Comment: You can't use `onload` on individual elements. Is it loaded with the page, or dynamically?

Comment: @Blazemonger div is loaded with page.

Answer (score 1):

If the div is loaded with the page, putting your code inside the `document.ready` will do. If it is loaded via `Ajax` or other, then after inserting the div, call the wanted code on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use this one

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Your code...

});
```